# Visual Studio 2017 won't create intermediate manifest file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, manifest

I am upgrading some big solution files (80 projects) from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2017.  I allowed VS to upgrade the solution and project files (they are all VC++ projects).

If you go to the "Linker" settings for the project, they are all set to generate an intermediate manifest.

[image: Intermediate Manifest settings]

I am running VS2017 as Administrator, and for each of the projects I try to build, I get an error similar to:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:...\intel_win32_Debug\bundle_creator\bundle_creator.exe.intermediate.manifest'

This works fine building the projects in VS2010.  In VS 2010, the intermediate manifest is produced and feeds the manifest tool, and the projects build.  The output directory exists and has intermediate .obj files, as well as a .pdb file. I also checked the directory privileges and ownership, and they appear to be in order.

This error happens for both debug/release builds.

Does anyone know why this would work in 2010 but not in 2017?

EDIT:  There is NO content in the linker trace log files. (Whereas plenty when done in VS2017).  Here is a sample project file.

EDIT 2: One *huge* difference I see is that in the VS2010 case I see trace logs for the mt.ext manifest tool, whereas in 2017 I don't.  So it appears like the manifest tool isn't running for some reason.  The manifest settings haven't changed - is there some setting in VS2017 for running the manifest tool before the linker?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Template|Win32">
      <Configuration>Template</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{FAA8F144-2DE8-4397-B694-FDA2BF43E610}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>bundle_creator</RootNamespace>
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.16299.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseOfMfc>false</UseOfMfc>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Template|Win32'">
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="..\..\..\..\..\build\properties\release.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="..\..\..\..\..\build\properties\debug.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.30319.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(CORE_LIBRARIES_DIR)\3rdParty\zlib\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>CONSOLE_MODE;OMIT_CRYPTO_SUPPORT=t;OMIT_SYSTEM_VALUES=t;_CONSOLE;__BUILD_STATIC_APPLICATION__;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <ResourceCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>CONSOLE_MODE;OMIT_CRYPTO_SUPPORT=t;OMIT_SYSTEM_VALUES=t;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ResourceCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>zlib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(CORE_LIBRARIES_DIR)\3rdparty\zlib\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(CORE_LIBRARIES_DIR)\3rdparty\zlib\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>CONSOLE_MODE;OMIT_CRYPTO_SUPPORT=t;OMIT_SYSTEM_VALUES=t;_CONSOLE;__BUILD_STATIC_APPLICATION__;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <ResourceCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>CONSOLE_MODE;OMIT_CRYPTO_SUPPORT=t;OMIT_SYSTEM_VALUES=t;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ResourceCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>zlib.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(CORE_LIBRARIES_DIR)\3rdparty\zlib\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="bundle_creator.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="common_bundle.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="bundler_version.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\..\libraries\core\library\basis\basis.vcxproj">
      <Project>{571b0731-ed86-476a-a723-9ecf75cb0d51}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\build_prerequisites.csproj">
      <Project>{28ba1c03-7e39-4ce2-993f-72a7772fa758}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties RESOURCE_FILE="bundler_version.rc" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

And here is the debug property sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <REPOSITORY_DIR Condition="'$(REPOSITORY_DIR)'==''">$(SolutionDir)</REPOSITORY_DIR>
    <BUILDER_DIR>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\..\..\build\</BUILDER_DIR>
    <BUILD_TOP>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\..\..\</BUILD_TOP>
    <LIBRARIES_DIR>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\..\..\libraries\</LIBRARIES_DIR>
    <CORE_LIBRARIES_DIR>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\..\..\libraries\core\</CORE_LIBRARIES_DIR>
    <SHARED_LIBRARIES_DIR>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\..\..\libraries\shared\</SHARED_LIBRARIES_DIR>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.30319.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
    <OutDir>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\binaries\</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(BUILDER_DIR)\properties\vcoptions.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Midl>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </Midl>
    <ClCompile>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <InlineFunctionExpansion>OnlyExplicitInline</InlineFunctionExpansion>
      <WholeProgramOptimization>false</WholeProgramOptimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <MinimalRebuild>false</MinimalRebuild>
      <StringPooling>false</StringPooling>
      <FunctionLevelLinking>false</FunctionLevelLinking>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <ResourceCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ResourceCompile>
    <Manifest>
      <AdditionalManifestFiles>$(IntDir)$(TargetFileName).intermediate.manifest;$(BUILDER_DIR)\properties\security_manifest.txt;%(AdditionalManifestFiles)</AdditionalManifestFiles>
    </Manifest>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\binaries;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <ProgramDatabaseFile>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\binaries\$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDatabaseFile>
      <ImportLibrary>$(REPOSITORY_DIR)\binaries\$(ProjectName).lib</ImportLibrary>
<AdditionalDependencies>msvcrtd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
<IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries>msvcrt.lib;mfc.lib</IgnoreSpecificDefaultLibraries> 
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: The build directory name is very unusual, surely that has something to do with it.  Nothing that can be guessed from your question, not without you either posting the .vcxproj file or the detailed build trace.

Comment: There is literally nothing in the linker trace log files.  They have no content in them.    The compile trace logs are identical between vs2010 and vs2017.  I'll post the project file.

Comment: As I said in the edit, it appears as if in VS2010 the mt.exe manifest tool is running and creating trace logs, whereas in 2017 it's not.  Is there a relevant setting in the manifest section where this tool runs before the linker?